# Copying attribute table to Excel in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, excel

In ArcMap I can select all rows in the attribute table, right click one of the grey boxes, copy and then paste into excel:

[image]

There is no Copy option in Pro.

How can this be done in ArcGIS Pro (without having to export the table)?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kind of hard to know, but you need to use a [shortcut](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/tables/keyboard-shortcuts-for-tables.htm#Edit), `CTRL+SHIFT+C`, which would

> Copy the selected records onto the clipboard.

Comment: That doesn't work (except for individual cells)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the copy paste functions into excel as mentioned with CTRL+SHIFT+C

to format as table in excel just go to

> Data-->Text to columns-->Delimited-->By Tab-->Ok

[image]

[image]

[image]